# “unary operator expected” in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, while-loop

I need a script to keep polling "receive_dir" directory till "stopfile" get written in the directory.

This has to run despite empty directory.

So far i have this but fails if receive_dir is empty with no files with "unary operator expected". Help !!

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

until [ $i = stopfile ]
 do
   for i in `ls receive_dir`; do
   time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
   echo $time
   echo $i;
  done
done
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Also, double quote the variables to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)

Answer (score 6):

This will do what you ask for (loop until the stop file exist). I added a "sleep 1" to lower resource usage. It's also good practice to use "#!/usr/bin/env ksh" as shebang.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

until [ -e receive_dir/stopfile ]
 do
   time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
   echo $time
   sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have empty dir, the

```
until [ $i = stopfile ]
```

is evaluated as

```
until [ = stopfile ]
```

what is ofcourse syntax error.

One comment: Never parse output from `ls`.

```
#!/bin/bash

do_something() {
    echo $(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S) "$1"
}

dir="."
until [[ -f "$dir/stopfile" ]]
do
    find "$dir" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
    do
        do_something "$filename"
    done
done
```

or (much slower)

```
do_something() {
    echo $(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S) "$1"
}
export -f do_something

dir="."
until [[ -f "$dir/stopfile" ]]
do
    find "$dir" -exec bash -c 'do_something "{}"' \;
done
```

Comment: I also need to echo the file in receive_dir.

Comment: @iaav don't understand. The `do_someting` prints the date and the filename. If you need it in a separate line, simply add another echo...

Comment: @iaav maybe - don't know ksh - using bash. your question is tagged bash.

Answer (score 1):

You're evaluating nothing, and the 'test' isn't able to evaluate it.

```
~> [ $empty_var = stopfile ]
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

First, don't parse ls:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

EDIT: Part of the issue is your loop is actually doing the test, try something like this (assuming receive_dir is relative):

@user000001 is right; my original find example would suffer the same issue, so this:

```bash
for i in receive_dir/*
do
    time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
    echo $time
    echo $i
    [ $i = stopfile ] && break
done
```

EDIT: Adding in another example based on your comment:

How about this...

```bash
FOUND="N"
while [ "${FOUND}" = "N" ]
do
    for i in receive_dir/*
    do
        time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
        echo $time
        echo $i
        [ "$i" = stopfile ] && FOUND="Y"
    done
sleep 60 
done
```

Comment: Indeed, I agree. I confess I'd rather handle it by using `[[ $i == stopfile ]]` to prevent problems arising from command substitution, but he's using ksh, and I think that isn't able to use the `[[ ]]` syntax.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is a builtin in both bash and ksh.

Comment: I also need to echo the file in receive_dir and have the loop run till stopfile is move in the directory.

Comment: How about this (also added to original post for readability):

`FOUND="N"
while [[ ${FOUND} == N ]]
do
 for i in receive_dir/*
 do
  time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
  echo $time
  echo $i
  [ $i = stopfile ] && FOUND="Y"
 done
done`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to monitor the status of the directory. For example, this script will run the loop until the file "stopfile" is touched.

```
until inotifywait "receive_dir" | grep "stopfile"
do 
    echo "running" 
done
echo "done"
```

The advantage is that these is no busy loop, and that you don't have to repeatedly call the (potentially expensive) find command